# Excel VBA referencing sheets by changing their name

Tags: excel, vba

I have `Sheet1` and it has some calculation:

- Many other sheets are referencing this sheet's two cells
- I have another sheet `Sheet2` with a different type of calculation deriving same sort of results.
- Somehow I want to change the name / codename of `Sheet2` so same cells are being referenced by other worksheets.

e.g. `Sheet1`'s cell `U30` has a result of a calculation and
`Sheet2`'s cell `U30` also has a result of a calculation

Either `Sheet1` or `Sheet2` can be used for calculations rest of the sheets depend on these sheets.

Other sheets are referencing it by =Sheet1!U30 when `Sheet1` is used as Calculation sheet

I want a way so that other sheets can reference =Sheet2!U30 automatically when `Sheet2` is used as Calculation sheet.

How can I achieve that?

Currently at the start of the workbook, user is presented with a form asking him which sheet you want to use as the calculation sheet. If he chooses `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` is set to hidden and vice versa.

Comment: You could use named ranges in the calculations in the other sheets, and use VBA to switch the "refers to range" for the ranges between the two sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use named ranges in the calculations in the other sheets, and use VBA to switch the "refers to range" for the ranges between the two sheets. – Tim Williams Oct 19 at 6:39